# Trouble in writing data on microcontroller using serial communication

Tags: java, com, serial-port, serial-communication, modbus

I am trying to send a command to the Microcontroller using serial communication, I can compile and run following code without any error but values are not being written on the register. What am I doing wrong?

**code**

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.comm.*;

import net.wimpi.modbus.net.SerialConnection;
import net.wimpi.modbus.util.SerialParameters;

import java.util.*;

public class SerTest {

public static void main(String[] args)  {



Enumeration portIdentifiers = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

CommPortIdentifier portId = null;  
while (portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements())
{
  CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers.nextElement();
  if(pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL &&
     pid.getName().equals("COM4")) 
  {
      portId = pid;
      break;
  }
}
if(portId == null)
{
  System.err.println("Could not find serial port "); // + wantedPortName);
  System.exit(1);
}

SerialPort port = null;

try {
  port = (SerialPort) portId.open(
      "name", // Name of the application asking for the port 
      10000   // Wait max. 10 sec. to acquire port
  );
} catch(PortInUseException e) {
  System.err.println("Port already in use: " + e);
  System.exit(1);
}

try {
port.setSerialPortParams(

    9600 , SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
    SerialPort.PARITY_EVEN);
}   catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}


BufferedReader is = null;  
PrintStream    os = null;

try {
is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(port.getInputStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println("Can't open input stream: write-only");
is = null;
}



try {
os = new PrintStream(port.getOutputStream(), true);

} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}



// Actual data communication would happen here
os.print("08050080FF008D4B");


os.flush(); 


if (is != null)
try {
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (os != null) os.close();
if (port != null) port.close();

} 

}
```

I suspect problem is in this line

```
os.print("08050080FF008D4B");
```

is this a right method of sending command to the microcontroller?

**Meaning of command**

```
08- Controller ID,
05- MODBUS function for coil writing,
0080- Address of a register where value is to be written,
FF00- Boolean value,
8D4B- CRC checksum ,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending the string `08050080FF008D4B`.  You probably want to be sending those as *bytes* instead of the string value.  The first byte that you are sending to the device is `0`, which is `0x30` in hex.  From your string and meaning of command, you probably want the first byte to be `0x08`.

So, something like this would probably work(note that without knowing anything more about what you're working with, I can't say for certain):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{ 0x08,0x05,0x00,(byte)0x80,(byte)0xFF,0x00,(byte)0x8D,(byte)0x4B };
//Later on in your code....
os.write( bytes );
```

Comment: @quetzalcoatl My bad I am aware that (byte)0xDC and (byte)0x8D are completely different values. however both MODBUS commands dose the same job or me so I accidentally wrote (byte)0xDC instead of (byte)0x8D,in fact I replaced the original command with completely different command, anyways thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe: Heh.. my, I wouldn't have a chance to notice that:) Thanks for the note!